# Why does the Sharepoint tab at the top of the screen not reflect the site name in the settings?

Tags: error, view

About a week ago, I changed the site name of my Sharepoint site in settings > site information > site name. When I open the site, the new site name will show on the tab for about half a second then switch back to the old site name.

How can I ensure that the site name in the settings is the site name being shown on the tab at the top of the page/browser? / Why is this happening?

Comment: Sound's like a caching issue. Same result in a different browser? Use Ctrl + F5 to make a hard refresh in the browser to see if it helps.

Comment: Is this site connected with Office 365 Group?